# Why are template arguments not deduced automatically in that example?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

While playing around with variadic templates I came around that:

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> 
{
    tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

    T tail;
};
```

I want just learn to understand what's going on here: We can instantiate such tuple by

```
tuple<int, double, const char*, const char*, const char*> myTuple(1234, 33.444, "I", "like", "C++");
```

but not with:

```
tuple myTuple2(1234, 33.444, "I", "like", "C++");
```

Why is the compiler not able to infer automatically the types from the list of given types?

If I do

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& first, T& second) {
   T aux = first;
   first = second;
   second = aux;
}

...
...

swap<int>(a, b);
swap(a, b);
```

both variants are possible. Is that not possible for variadic template arguments? What are the rules C++ uses for inferring types?

Answer (score 12):

```
tuple myTuple2(1234, 33.444, "I", "like", "C++");
```

Is a variable declaration and initialization by calling the constructor, while

```
swap(a, b);
```

Is a function call.

While C++ always had [function template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), it didn't support [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) until C++17. That is the reason why [`std::make_tuple`](https://godbolt.org/z/zbwVKZ) exists. Because you couldn't do `std::tuple t(1, 2.4)` and so you had a function and could write `auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2.4)`.

So you need C++17 and for your example you also need a deduction guide:

```
template <class... Ts>
tuple(Ts...) -> tuple<Ts...>;
```

And [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/zbwVKZ).

Comment: Maybe expand the answer by pointing out that the normal answer pre-C++17 is to define a function `make_tuple` and use like `auto myTuple2 = make_tuple(1234, 33.444, "I", "like", "C++");`